# Как удалить ping в стриминговых ивентах?

Tags: python, async-await, uvicorn

У меня есть функция:

```
async def event_generator():
    stream_gen = new_messages()
    while True:
        if await request.is_disconnected():
            break
        try:
            item = next(stream_gen)
            yield Item(
                user_uuid=user_uuid, session_id=session_id, message_id=item[0], token_id=item[0], message=item[1])
        except StopIteration:
            return

        await asyncio.sleep(STREAM_DELAY)
```

Она возвращает стриминговые ивенты в формате

```
data: user_uuid='we' token_id=51 session_id=23234234 message=' of'

data: user_uuid='we' token_id=52 session_id=23234234 message=' these'

data: user_uuid='we' token_id=53 session_id=23234234 message=' titles'

event: ping
data: 2023-04-21 14:12:09.880975

data: user_uuid='we' token_id=54 session_id=23234234 message=' or'

data: user_uuid='we' token_id=55 session_id=23234234 message=' provide'
```

Иногда ивентом есть событие типа `event: ping data: 2023-04-21 14:12:09.880975`

Я не хочу чтобы это событие отображалось.
Т. е. должно быть так:

```
data: user_uuid='we' token_id=51 session_id=23234234 message=' of'

data: user_uuid='we' token_id=52 session_id=23234234 message=' these'

data: user_uuid='we' token_id=53 session_id=23234234 message=' titles'

data: user_uuid='we' token_id=54 session_id=23234234 message=' or'

data: user_uuid='we' token_id=55 session_id=23234234 message=' provide'
```

Вот часть кода для лучшего понимания

```
@unsync
async def message_stream(
        request: Request,
        system_info,
        mm_client,
        table_id,
        separator,
        message: str,
        user_uuid: str,
        session_id: int):

    ...

    def new_messages():
        str_response = ""
        messages.append({"role": "user", "content": message, "time": str(datetime.datetime.now(timezone))})

        status = False
        while not status:
            try:
                completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                    model=model, messages=[{"role": i["role"], "content": i["content"]} for i in messages],
                    temperature=0.03, stream=True, request_timeout=5)
                for num, line in enumerate(completion):
                    token = line['choices'][0]['delta'].get('content', "")
                    yield num, token
                    str_response += token
                status = True

            except Exception as e:
                logger.warning(f"Session {session_id} with ChatGPT error {e} for the user {user_uuid}")
                time.sleep(1)

        ...

    async def event_generator():
        stream_gen = new_messages()
        while True:
            if await request.is_disconnected():
                break
            try:
                item = next(stream_gen)
                yield Item(
                    user_uuid=user_uuid, session_id=session_id, message_id=item[0], token_id=item[0], message=item[1])
            except StopIteration:
                return

            await asyncio.sleep(STREAM_DELAY)

    return EventSourceResponse(event_generator())


@app.get('/key_hire_stream')
async def key_hire(request: Request, message: str, user_uuid: str, session_id: int):
    return message_stream(
        request=request, system_info=key_hire_system_info, mm_client=key_hire_memcached_client,
        table_id=key_hire_table_id, separator="++++", message=message, user_uuid=user_uuid,
        session_id=session_id).result()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, log_level="debug")
```

Как я могу удалить `event: ping` с возвращаемых событий?

Благодарю

Comment: Какую библиотеку вы используете?

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn я использую fastapi и sse_starlette. Добавил больше кода для лучшего понимания. Благодарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одно из решений - **установить огромный интервал** для пинга.

```
event_source = EventSourceResponse(eg)
event_source.ping_interval = 600 # <---
```

Значение интервала указывается в секундах, в данном случае - 10 минут.